# MYSQL SELECT all rows with timestamp 1 to 2 weeks old

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to get all rows that are older then 1 week, and younger then 2 weeks. This is the SQL syntax that I jus tried:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(ip)
FROM visits
WHERE time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10080 MINUTE AND
      time <= NOW() - 20160 MINUTE
```

Where `20160 MINUTE` = 2 weeks and `10080 MINUTE` = 1 week. I get the following error:

> 1064 - Er is iets fout in de gebruikte syntax bij 'MINUTE LIMIT 0, 25' in regel 1

(Sorry error in Dutch)

"#1060 - There went something wrong in the used syntaxt at 'MINUTE LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1"

Thank you for your time,,

Comment: You have no limit in the query in your question.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I have no qlue why phpmyadmin gives me that as error @GordonLinoff

Comment: If you can, consider using `time BETWEEN ... AND ...` instead.

Comment: Does not look like this is the query that is giving the error as `LIMIT 0, 25` is not part of the query you show us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you intend:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip
FROM visits
WHERE time <= NOW() - INTERVAL 10080 MINUTE AND
      time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 20160 MINUTE;
```

Note that this fixes the syntax problem (the missing `INTERVAL`).  It also adjusts the comparisons so they should be in the correct direction.

Given your explanation, you might consider:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip
FROM visits
WHERE time <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND
      time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK;
```